# Possible to execute builds concurrently in Jenkins if pulling project code from Git?

Tags: git, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

I have a project which runs a series of automation tests within Jenkins, the project code is pulled from Git which is stored within Microsoft TFS, when I have tried to execute two builds at the same time within Jenkins I seem to be getting errors such as JAR file related exceptions, is it even possible to run two jobs at the same time when using the same project code which is pulled from Git?

Example Exception 1:

```
  11:22:14 [ERROR] Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project AutoFramework: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users\Joe.Blogs\Desktop\AutomatedTest\AutoFramework\target\generated-sources
```

Example Exception 2:

```
 Failed to execute goal org.apache.maven.plugins:maven-clean-plugin:2.5:clean (default-clean) on project AutoFramework: Failed to clean project: Failed to delete C:\Users\Joe.Blogs\Desktop\AutomatedTest\AutoFramework\target\surefire\surefirebooter537025062701550661.jar
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem here is that the job you are trying to run concurrently has the same shared workspace, once you overcome that hurdle, you can run as many jobs as you'd like concurrently (per Jenkins executors limit - which can be controlled from Jenkins settings).

The way I implemented that on my Jenkins, is by using clone to a subdirectory under additional behaviors.

I then clone it to a folder named as the `$BUILD_ID`.

[image]

So for example:

When I run job 'Job-A' (lets say build number is #55), its `$WORKSPACE` is located at `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Job-A/`
When the git clone runs, it clones it to `/var/lib/jenkins/workspace/Job-A/55` - you then have to make sure the rest of the jobs works in your nested workspace and not in `$WORKSPACE`.

I define a variable at the start of the job called `NESTED_WORKSPACE = $WORKSPACE/$BUILD_ID`, and then instead of using `$WORKSPACE`, I use `$NESTED_WORKSPACE`

This makes everything relative to your build and will allow you to run jobs concurrently.

One big issue to remember - if your git repo is large, this can definitely kill your Jenkins box, as every build is a clone, make sure to either clean-up old jobs somehow, or make sure you have sufficient storage.

In my case this was actually a big problem as the repo eventually got to 100's of MBs (.. Dont ask me why -_- .. ), but eventually I had to implement a sparse checkout which only cloned the files I needed - I did that using a custom script and not using the git plugin, just FYI.

Comment: do you know why it would take allot longer to compile the cloned build?

Comment: @DeltaBluee not sure I understand the question, are you saying it takes longer to compile when it runs in parallel?

Comment: that is correct, for example project A [Non cloned] project will execute/ compile and complete the build within 50seconds however project B [cloned project] will take between 3-5mins long, thanks again for your help

Comment: @DeltaBluee Git clone itself might take a while depending on repo size and latency, other than that compiling is CPU intensive, and compiling in parallel may take longer, but should not be so significant. I would say most of the overhead is from how long it takes to clone.. you can probably look at timestamps in the console output to figure out what takes so long between the two job instances.